# SPFX webpart creation Error: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am creating SPFX webpart. Without doing any code changes i am executing gulp serve. I am getting below error for this. What could be the issue?

[image]

GULP version:

CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're using node 12 and gulp 3. That combination does not work: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2324

A previous workaround from Jan. does not work either: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246

**Solution:** Either upgrade to gulp 4 or downgrade to an earlier node.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I have updated gulp. But still i am getting same error. I have mentioned Gulp version in question.

Comment: Can you try after downgrading gulp to 3.9.1 band node version to 8.11.3 ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using NodeJS 12.

The current supported LTS version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is Node.js v8.x and Node.js v10.x (recommended). Node.js v12.x is not currently supported. Notice that Node.js 9.x or 11.x versions are also not supported with SharePoint Framework development.